# Error sending socket [WinError 10061]No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it for Socket from Python to Android

Tags: android, python, sockets

I am sending a socket from a python script to my android phone and vice versa. When my android sends a packet to my python script it works but sending packets from python script to android gives this error:

```
Error sending socket  [WinError 10061] 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Note: When sending from android to python the function uses a different socket and different port. The error occurs here `s.connect((host, port))`
Here is my python code to send the packet:

```
try:
    s = socket.socket()
    host = "ip_address_of_android"
    port = 7801
    s.connect((host, port))
    print("connected")
    s.listen(5)
    print("sending")
    text = "hello"
    s.sendall(text.encode())
    s.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("Error sending socket ", e)
```

And here is my android studio code to receive the packet:

```
public String receives() {
    Socket socket;
    DataInputStream ds;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("ip_address_of_android", 7801);
        ds = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            result = ds.readUTF();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("error");
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am assuming it is an android firewall error but I have no idea how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- It is not an Android firewall error.
- Your code has mixed together the client & server logic in a nonsensical way.
- The server (Android) should `listen()` and `accept()`.
- The client (Python) should `connect()`. It should not `listen()`.

"Target machine actively refused it" indicates that the client successfully reached the server's network interface, but the server OS said, "no-one has port 7801 open, so there's nothing for me to connect you to." The Android side never opened 7801, because it never `listen()`-ed.